# What is the "unicode" mentioned in text_to_word_sequence() in text package?

Tags: text, python-3.5

My IDE was not able pick out the reference of unicode but it did not throw any errors as well (obviously since it is part of python libraries). But now I want to redefine the function as my own, and when I copy paste this function to my file "unicode" is not recognized and a compilation error is thrown. Is there anyone who knows what the unicode hear is referencing ?

```
def text_to_word_sequence(text,
                          filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\t\n',
                          lower=True, split=" "):
    """Converts a text to a sequence of words (or tokens).

    # Arguments
        text: Input text (string).
        filters: Sequence of characters to filter out.
        lower: Whether to convert the input to lowercase.
        split: Sentence split marker (string).

    # Returns
        A list of words (or tokens).
    """
    if lower:
        text = text.lower()

    if sys.version_info < (3,) and isinstance(text, unicode):
        translate_map = dict((ord(c), unicode(split)) for c in filters)
    else:
        translate_map = maketrans(filters, split * len(filters))

    text = text.translate(translate_map)
    seq = text.split(split)
    return [i for i in seq if i]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unicode` is a type in 2.x that refers to a string of characters instead of bytes (`str`). The equivalent in 3.x is `str` (as opposed to `bytes`).

Just remove the 2.x code path and that code will be fine (excepting bugs, of course).